# Dart nested collections - List<Map<String, Object>>

Tags: dart

I did a little Basic and Ada programming 25 years ago, but never got any deeper ... now my mind isn't as sharp as it used to be so I bought a few courses about Dart and Flutter on Udemy, but instructors don't really teach programming... They start advanced topics like complex data structures in the first lessons in 3 minute long video and I'm completely lost.

I'm trying to make some sense on my own about nested collections, researching on the internet, but i can't figure out how to access double nested collections (list/maps inside a list of maps). Can you guys share some links / courses on the topic.

Here is some sample code, I managed to access to the first map data, but I don't know how to get the items in the 'ingredient' list, neither the data in the 'macros' map... How can i now the 'protein' in my dishes? Thanks in advance.

```
void main() {
  var recipes = [
    {
      'name': 'Hoisin Chicken Lettuce Cups',
      'type': 'Salad',
      'ingredients': ['mango', 'hoisin sauce', 'chicken breasts', 'romaine lettuce', 'cress'],
      'calories': 289,
      'macros': {
          'fat': 9.6,
          'sat_fat': 1.8,
          'protein': 31.3,
          'carbs': 20.3,
          'sugar': 19.2,
          'salt': 1.3,
          'fibre': 2.5,
        },
    },
    {
      'name': 'Smoked Salmon Plates',
      'type': 'Salad',
      'ingredients': ['cucumber', 'dill', 'smoked salmon', 'avocado', 'cottage cheese'],
      'calories': 246,
      'macros': {
          'fat': 17.7,
          'sat_fat': 3.9,
          'protein': 17.1,
          'carbs': 4.4,
          'sugar': 3.2,
          'salt': 1.5,
          'fibre': 1.2,
        },
    },

  ];

  // Managing to accest collection data... How to get protein amount? 
  // How to know 'macros' lenght? ...

  print(recipes);
  print(recipes.length);
  print('---------------------------------------');
  print(recipes[1]);
  print(recipes[1].length);
  print(recipes[1]['ingredients']);
  print(recipes[1]['macros']);
  print('---------------------------------------');

}
```

Comment: `recipes[1]['macros']['protein']`.

The `recipes[1]['macros']` is a map, so you look up by (string) key the same way you looked up `'macros'` in `recipes[1]`.

Comment: I tried this before, but never realized the error vscode output was about null safety. I'm trying to add a null check without luck... Can you give me and example how to perform a conditional call in this example?

Comment: Ah, so your `recipes[1]['macros']` has type `Object?`. It's not just being nullable which is an issue, even adding `!['protein']` doesn't work. You need `(recipes[1]['macros'] as Map)['protein']`.

Comment: Wow, thank for your reply. Even i don't understand the why you made my day, now i know how to access the data.